# call back function after file read in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am dealing with this problem from quite a while, please suggest me a solution:

For android app development, I am using phonegap framework.

I have a async function readFromFile() which reads the json file (which is updated using a user data everytime) stored in SD card, and stores the text result into the global variable, Next I have a function populatePageContents() which reads the global variable, and populates the page's html from the json data.

I want the populatePageContents() function to be called after readFromFile() function has finished reading the file data into global variable.

I tried using someting like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

globalVariable = '';

readFromFile(); // Uses phonegap's file API to read file and puts result into global variable
setTimeout(function() { populatePageContents(JSON.parse(globalVariable)); } , 500);

</script>
```

The above method works sometimes, but not always. Please suggest some better use of callback functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use callbacks for making it work everytime

U can use something like this:

```
readFromFile(function(data){
```

populatePageContents(JSON.parse(data));

});

And your readFromFile function should look like this :

```
readFromFile(callback){
```

/*****read file phonegap code*****//

callback();
}